# Encrypting text field on form via Java applet; browser is caching encrypted text; how to cache plaintext?

Tags: java, jsp, caching, encryption, applet

I have a Java Applet which encrypts text entered on a form text field, just before the submission of the form.  It works well but the browser -- Google Chrome, in particular -- is caching the text field, AFTER it's encrypted.  I want the browser to cache the field, prior to its text getting encrypted.

Google Chrome asks if I want to save my password, after I submit the form.  Unfortunately, it saves the encrypted field, not the plaintext field.

How do I ensure the browser caches the form text field, prior to the Java Applet encrypts it?

Thank you.

Comment: When do you encrypt, during "onSubmit" or before?

Comment: I encrypt before I issue document.formname.submit() in JavaScript.  The encryption occurs within an onClick event, i.e. onClick="return VerifyandSubmit();".  Thank you for your help.

Comment: In that case, have you tried encrypting during "onSubmit"? Maybe you can also try filling in another form and submitting that instead? In that case your original form can just stay the way it is, without any chance of sending out plain text (e.g. when JavaScript is disabled).

Comment: Yes!  I modified the onClick event with an onSubmit and it was a success!  Thank you!  If you can sum up the solution in the question area, I can give you a check.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Added the comments as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried encrypting during `"onSubmit"`? In that case the form data won't be changed until the last moment, when the browser is already performing the POST.

You may also try filling in another form and submitting that instead. In that case your original form can just stay the way it is, without any chance of sending out plain text (e.g. when JavaScript is disabled).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I modified my onClick event to an onSubmit event, and that permitted Google Chrome to cache the plaintext.  I thought I had to create an encrypted cookie and a few other steps that might have fixed it.  But your suggestions proved to be the best way.  Thank you, again!